# Rails Routing order impacts performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, routes

Just a quick question about Rails routing route definition order?

Is it better for more frequent routes to be defined higher up in the `routes.rb` file than infrequent ones?

Like I get a million hits on `/a` and a hundred hits on `/b` in a very large route file.

Am I going to get better performance if /a is defined on the very top of the route file?

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, you will get better performance since the `routes.rb` file has to be read from top to bottom, because Rails matches the routes to the first available match it finds.

Whether this has any noticeable effect on performance is hard to say, and you would have to benchmark that for yourself really. The routes file would have to be gigantic I'd imagine for it to have any noticeable effect.

You just have to be careful not to move the routes so that a more general route is above a more specific one.